# How to get current category in Magento2 without using Registry or ObjectManager on PDP?

Tags: magento2

How can i get current category in magento2 ?

I want to get category name on product details page.

As using Registry is deprecated and using ObjectManager is not good practice.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your theme's form.phtml file. If form.phtml is not present in your theme copy it from Magento_Catalog module to your theme.

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/form.phtml
```

to

```
app/design/frontend/{Vendorname}/{Themename}/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/form.phtml
```

Paste the code below

```
<?php echo $block->getProduct()->getCategory()->getName(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**To get the current category:**

**use block class**: Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View

**Get product using**: $block->getCurrentCategory() in your phtml or use the class and get in the block file.

Hope it Helps.Happy coding!!

Answer (score 0):

you should use

```
$categoryId = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('id', false);
```

and then with instantiated

`\Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface` use

```
$this->categoryRepository->get($categoryId);
```